# Crear lista de n elementos sabiendo el inicio y el paso

Tags: python, numpy

La función `range` (o `arange` en NumPy) te permite especificar el `inicio`, el final y el `paso`, pero si en vez de conocer el final sabes el número `n` de elementos que ha de tener la lista, ¿cómo podrías crearla?

Algo equivalente a hacer en R:

```
vector = inicio + paso * (0:n)
```

Comment: Por ejemplo `vector = inicio + paso *  range(0, numero + 1)`?

Comment: Me devuelve un error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'range'`.

Comment: Si, es que `range` solo genera rangos entre enteros, con `float` se podría hacer algo, pero ahora sí amerita una respuesta.

Comment: El número de elementos es un entero pero tanto el inicio como el paso son decimales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En mi opinión, la manera más *nativa* de hacer esto en Python es usando los siguientes elementos:

- `itertools.count`: El cual es un iterador cuyo método de inicialización recibe dos valores: `start` y `step`, además de que su método `__next__` no tiene un criterio de parada.
- Comprehensión de lista: Para crear la lista de salida, basado en un `range()` que determine su longitud, y usando `next()` para invocar los valores del iterador `count`.

El código sería (Dado un **inicio en 1.5**, **un paso de 0.5** y una longitud de la lista de salida de **10 elementos**):

```
from itertools import count


numbers = count(start=1.5, step=0.5)
output = [next(numbers) for _ in range(10)]
```

`output` contendrá:

```
[1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Se puede optar también por la función `arange()` de numpy

```
arange = arange(1,10,1.3)
print(arange)
#resultado -> [1. , 2.3, 3.6, 4.9, 6.2, 7.5, 8.8]
```

Sin embargo la pregunta es `pero si en vez de conocer el final sabes el número de elementos que ha de tener la lista, ¿cómo podrías crearla?`
Se puede hacer siempre y cuando se especifique el **paso**

```
def myarange(start,step,numElemt):
     myarray=[]
     myarray.append(start)
     for e in range(numElemt-1):
          myarray.append(start+step)
          start=start+step
          print(start)
     return myarray
```

Y solo ejecutas la función

```
ma=myarange(1,2,5)
print(ma)
```

Y el resultado será

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

A `numElemt` le resto 1 ya que al principio se le añadió el primer elemto, si quieres puedes omitir el `-1` pero la diferencia con arange seria que no te devuelve el número si es mayor al especificado en `stop` y tendrás un elemto más del especificado

Comment: Reitero mi comentario, R tiene la particularidad que `seq(1,3) == 1, 2, 3`, en python, tanto `range()` como `numpy.arrange()` será `1, 2`

Comment: Prueba mi código y veras que da el mismo resultado que en R, solo pon ```ma=myarange(1,1,3)``` y haz un ```print(ma)```

Comment: Christian, no estoy atacando tu solución, solo quiero dejar claro las diferencias. Saludos.

Comment: @Patricio Moracho lo siento, es que no conozco nada de R, disculpa mi ignorancia.

Comment: Amigo Christian, es un error que declares `myarray` fuera de la función. Recuerda que las listas son objetos mutables. Si llamas la función dos veces, la operación se aplicará sobre exactamente el mismo objeto.

Comment: Gracias no había tomado en cuenta eso

Answer (score 2):

Con `Python` se me ocurre una implementación super básica:

```
def myrange(start, stop, step=1):

  istart = int(start)
  n = int(stop - start)

  for e in range(0, istart + n):
    valor = start + (step * e)
    if valor <= stop:
      yield valor
```

Y funcionaría así:

```
print(list(myrange(1, 10)))
print(list(myrange(1, 10, 1.3)))
print(list(myrange(1.5, 10.5)))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1.0, 2.3, 3.6, 4.9, 6.2, 7.5, 8.8]
[1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5]
```

Sin embargo, te sugiera que verifiques [este código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60844608/6836377) que parece ser una implementación más rigurosa de la función `seq()` de R

Comment: Y por que no utilizar la función ```arange()``` de numpy?

Comment: Claro por que no?, era una de las opciones que preguntó el OP, mi respuesta es por ahora sola la opción de `range()` de Python base

Comment: @christian podrías responder la pregunta y así tendríamos un ejemplo con `arange`

Comment: @Adrián es solo una función, al igual que ```sum()``` no hay mucho código, es solo una línea pero si en realidad se prefiere las 2 demostraciones, pongo mi respuesta

Comment: Christian,  no es tan directo, el autor pide cierta consistencia con la función `seq()` de R, tampoco es que sea tan complejo, pero lo que digo es que `arrange()` o `range()` no son compatibles por si mismas con las secuencias de R

Comment: Obviamente hay diferencias en el lenguaje sin embargo el en las etiquetas puso __python__ y dio un ejemplo en el lenguaje  __R__

Comment: Si claro Christian, estoy de acuerdo que es opinable, solo me parece importante en el contexto de lo que el OP menciona "Algo equivalente a hacer en R", que queden claras las diferencias

Comment: En el enlace que adjuntas sugieren usar `linspace` de NumPy; lo intenté ayer y me daba un error, volveré a probar. Lo que quería encontrar era algo ya implementado en alguna librería que te permita emular lo que se puede hacer de forma nativa en R, sin tener que recurrir en Python a funciones creadas ad hoc.

Comment: `linspace` también requiere un `stop`, no me sirve.